# Questions about harmonic functions and distribution.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-functions

If harmonic functions converges in the distribution sense to a distribution. Then can we prove that the functions are actually converges uniformly to a function on every compact set. And the limit function is actually also harmonic?
I'm totally stuck by this exercise and I have achieved nothing. So please someone help me with this problem, thanks....

Comment: I believe this is just an application of Weyl's Lemma, with multiplying by bump functions on the compact subsets of convergence.

Comment: Can you tell me what does the lemma state? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here you go: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl's_lemma_(Laplace_equation)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how to use this lemma to show that the sequence will converge uniformly in a compact set?

Comment: I have not thought about that as much--but once you do that it seems feasible to use Weyl's lemma to prove that its harmonic. The only thing, which I assume you would have thought of, is Harnack's Principle--but I don't know how to apply that directly here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think this partial answer is enough for me at this stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convergence in the sense of distributions has a very nice property: the limit of derivatives is the derivative of the limit. Precisely, if $f_n\to f$ as distributions, then for every test function $\phi$ we have $\langle f_n,\nabla \phi\rangle \to \langle f,\nabla \phi\rangle$ (since $\nabla \phi$ is just a bunch of test functions), which by definition of distributional derivative means  $\nabla f_n\to \nabla \phi$.

In particular, $f_n\to f$ implies $\Delta f_n\to \Delta f$ in the sense of distributions. But $\Delta f_n\equiv 0$, hence $\Delta f\equiv 0$. Weyl's lemma tells us that both $f$ and $f_n$ are harmonic functions.

It remains to upgrade the convergence to locally uniform. Harmonic functions have another nice property: $f(a)=\int f\varphi$ for any test function of the form $\varphi(x)=\psi(|x-a|)$ such that $\int \varphi =1$. (Proof is a sub-exercise.) By distributional convergence, $\int f_n\varphi\to \int f \varphi$, hence $f_n(a)\to f(a)$. This is pointwise convergence; I leave it for you to upgrade it to locally uniform.

Comment: Is it because when constrained the domain to a compact set, the test function space is a Frechet space. And use the resonance theorem to make the convergence locally uniform?

Comment: @lee That is an interesting idea; please post the details if it works. My personal inclination was to forget distributions and instead prove a lemma saying "if pointwise limit of harmonic functions is harmonic, then the convergence is locally uniform". But then the proof escaped me...

Comment: By Banach-Steinhaus theorem, they are equicontinuous, then the locally uniformness follows immediately when we apply the Ascoli's theorem.

Comment: At least when holomorphic functions are involved, it [seems](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113240/pointwise-convergence-of-sequences-of-holomorphic-functions-to-holomorphic-funct) that pointwise convergence to a holomorphic function is not enough to deduce locally uniform convergence and that a similar example works also for harmonic functions.

Comment: @levap Thanks for the reference. Indeed, taking real or imaginary part of a holomorphic counterexample we get a harmonic one. Interesting.