# What an example of holomorphic function $f_n\to f$ s.t. $f$ is not holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, uniform-convergence, analytic-functions, pointwise-convergence

I think that if the sequence $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ (and not uniformly), $f$ is not always holomorphic. Then I searched concrete examples of $f_n$ such that $f$ is not holomorphic, but I couldn't find such a $f_n$. As a side note, I thought of $U$ as a unit disk $D\colon=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid |z|<1\}$ when I searched that.

Is there the concrete example? I would appreciate it if you propose that example!

Comment: It is true that pointwise limit of holomorphic functions may not be holomorphic, but I don't see how the theorem you've mentioned should imply it.

Comment: Still, it does suggest it

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113240/pointwise-convergence-of-sequences-of-holomorphic-functions-to-holomorphic-funct) is a counterexample

Comment: @Gae.S. Sorry, the way I said it was not good. Please forget the proposition which I wrote in the opening sentence.

Comment: @TitoEliatron It is an "open" and "dence" set, but I think of only an "open" set.

Comment: "This implies that..." nope, this does not imply anything as you do not know whether the proposition is optimal. It merely suggests that it is true

Comment: I deleted a description of the proposition.